# How to filter the data with mysql where more than two ID's have same name

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to filter data like in the image, i tried

```
select  distinct id, name  
from table 
where name in (select name 
                from table group by name, id 
                having 1 < count(*) )
```

but it is not giving me the expected result.

Comment: Add sample data and expected result as text not as image and please tell us the logic behind this

Comment: How do you get ID=4, Name=a

Comment: please rethink your example data is wrong , its showing that you are filtering some random data while it has nothing to do with the any logic . like how can you filter Id 4 with a name "a" which does not exisits

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 2`

This should get all the names that appear more than 2 times and also have more than 2 ids.